# Large Graph Visualization in browser

Tags: javascript, graph-visualization, graphstream

I'm trying to visualize in browser a dynamic graph that is of size 300,000 nodes and 1.5 million edges using GraphStream library and websockets. I tried D3.js and Sigma.js as of now. I'm leaving it to JS library to handle positioning of nodes and edges. Both of them do not scale ( browser becomes un-responsive). I guess it is a short-coming of any DOM based library. Is it possible to visualize a graph of such a scale in browser using the available JS libraries. I would like to know about if there are any tricks to achieve this without much noticable performance downfall.

Comment: Hello, any updates on your progress?